# Spawning two threads by one command

Tags: git-bash

I want to execute two commands in the background in git bash:
`git gui &` and `gitk &`
I tried this:
`$ git gui & && gitk &`
and got:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close :-)

```
git gui & gitk &
```

should do the trick.